# Powershell ReadKey() case sensitive

Tags: powershell

In my script I need to get 1 character from user and process it immediately whithout waiting for an Enter.
Additionally, I want to treat the character case-sensitive.

```
write-host("Please press a or A:")
$choice = ($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey(('NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp,IncludeKeyDown'))).character

if($choice -ceq "a")
{
    write-host("You pressed a");
}
elseif($choice -ceq "A")
{
    write-host("You pressed A");
}
else
{
    Write-Host("You pressed neither a nor A")
}
Pause
```

The issue of this code is when I try to press "A", it shows "*You pressed neither a nor A*".
The reason is to type "A" I have to press *Shift* first, Powershell detects *Shift* pressed and it process immediately without waiting for an A.

Anyone has idea how to solve this?

Comment: Check the documentation [ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar?view=netframework-4.8) There is e comment  // Ignore if Alt or Ctrl is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet:

```
if ( $Host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost' ) {
    Write-Host "Please press a or A:"
    Do  {
            $choice = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey(14)
        } until ( $choice.VirtualKeyCode -in @( 48..90) )

    if ( $choice.Character -ceq "a") {
        Write-Host "You pressed a";
    }
    elseif ( $choice.Character -ceq "A") {
        Write-Host "You pressed A";
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "You pressed neither a nor A ($($choice.Character))";
    }
} else {
    # e.g. Windows PowerShell ISE Host:
    # the "ReadKey" method or operation is not implemented.
    Write-Host '$Host.Name -neq ConsoleHost' -ForegroundColor Magenta
}
```

As currently written, `$choice.VirtualKeyCode -in @( 48..90)` condition allows some (limited) subset of printable characters. Adjust it with respect to [Keys Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8)…

Answer (score 1):

Does the below make up for what is expected,

```
($key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()) | % { if ($_.VirtualKeyCode -eq '16') {
            $key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()
        }
        $Choice = $key.Character
        if ($Choice -ceq "a"){
            "`rYou pressed 'a'"
        }
        elseif ($Choice -ceq "A"){
            "`rYou pressed 'A'"
        }
        else {
            "`rYou neither pressed 'a' nor 'A'"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to only react to keypresses that result in a *printable character*, and then evaluate which character was pressed via a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch).

```
# Wait for a printable character to be pressed.
while (($char=($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')).Character) -eq 0) {}

# Evaluate it.
switch -CaseSensitive ($char) {
  'a' { 'You pressed a' }
  'A' { 'You pressed A' }
  default { 'You pressed neither a nor A' }
}
```

Note: While modifier keys  <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> *by themselves* do not count as keypresses, *combinations* with a printable character do; therefore, for instance, <kbd>Alt-a</kbd> is treated the same as `'a'`, and <kbd>Control-a</kbd> as control character START OF HEADING, [`U+0001`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1).

If you want to avoid that, use the following variation instead:

```
# Wait for a printable character to be pressed, but only if not combined
# with Ctrl or Alt.
while (($key=$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')).Character -eq 0 -or 
       $key.ControlKeyState -notin 0, 'ShiftPressed') {}
$char = $key.Character
```

Note: This works on *Windows only* - on Unix-like platforms, the `.ControlKeyState` property is apparently *always* `0`.

However, if you use [`[Console]::ReadKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.ReadKey) instead, you can make it work on Unix-like platforms too - which assumes that you're willing to assume that your script always runs in a console (terminal), and not other kinds of PowerShell hosts.

```
# Wait for a printable character to be pressed, but only if not combined
# with Ctrl or Alt.
while (($key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)).KeyChar -eq 0 -or 
       $key.Modifiers -notin 0, 'Shift') {}
$char = $key.KeyChar
```