# Why does Read-Host require to hit enter 2 times enter before sending result?

Tags: powershell, read-host

I have a simeple loop to read for text and also detect the escape **ESC** `[0x1b = chr(27)]` key, to quit.

**The Expected Behaviour**

```bash
<Enter loop> 

<Enter any string, such as "AT" and hit Return>
# Some Output
<Repeat above OR>, 
...
<Hit the ESC (Escape) key to exit loop>

<Exit Loop>
```

**Actual Behaviour**

I have to:

- Hit [Enter]  button 2 times, after entering a string and before getting any output.
- ESC key to exit loop does not seem to work.

---

**The Code:**

```
        do {
            $key = if ($host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable) { $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown') }
            if ($port.IsOpen) {
                $at = Read-Host
                $port.Write("${at}`r")
            } else {
                Write-Host -Fo Yellow "[INFO] Port was Closed!"
                break
            }
    
        } until ($key.VirtualKeyCode -eq 27)    # Repeat until a 'ESC'
    }
```

---

**Q: *How Can I fix the above to get the intended functionality?***

(*Why do I need to hit enter 2 times before the input string is processed?*)

---

Experimenting, this one-liner is behaving very weird...

```
while (1) { if($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode -eq 81) { break };$s=''; $s=Read-Host; if ($s -ne "w") { Write-Host ": $s" -Non | Out-Host } else { "Hit W!"}  }
```

If you want to list the names and codes of all available *keys*, you can use:

```
1..255| ForEach-Object { '{0} = {1}' -f $_, [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]$_ }

# <output>
...
16 = ShiftKey
17 = ControlKey
18 = Menu
19 = Pause
...
```

Comment: 1 for `ReadKey` 1 for `Read-Host`

Comment: Something like this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/76017288/15339544 if you dont need a timeout then it would be even simpler. But essentially, get rid of `Read-Host` and write your own wrapper around it so it returns as soon as you press ESC

Comment: Aaah. Weird. So I need to do the ESC key check inside the `if()` statement then? I don't see how to do this properly now..

Comment: Wouldn't placing `if ($key.VirtualKeyCode -eq 27) { break }` right after `$key = ...` solve your problem?

Comment: No, it's weird. The ESC key is never detected while having to enter [ENTER] 2 times in order for the input string to be processed.

Comment: Another weird thing I noticed, is that (in a different application), is that when I set `($key.VirtualKeyCode -eq 81)`, which is the code for upper an case "Q" (d81), it actually accepting the lowercase "q" (with ASCII d113) instead.

Comment: mm i think mklement0 is right, try removing `if ($host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable)` and just do `if($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode -eq 27) { break }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Should I still use the `until(...)` part?

Comment: @not2qubit, I'm unclear on the desired behavior: while the `Read-Host` prompt is up, you want ESC to abort the prompt? Only when it is the first keystroke? Also the `.VirtualKeyCode -eq 81` behavior is expected, because it describes a _key_ rather than a _character_ - the latter is reflected in the `.Character` property.

Comment: @mklement0 Aah, ok. So how can I detect the ESC key correctly and exit the loop? (I have updated the OP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution preserves the usual [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Read-Host) command-line editing experience, so that editing the string being typed by the user is possible:

```bash
$wshell = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell) # For sending keystrokes
while ($true) {
  # Solicit an initial keypress without echoing it.
  $c = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').Character
  if ($c -eq [char] 27) { # ESC pressed? Exit the loop.
    'You pressed ESC - Quitting'; break
  } 
  elseif ($c -in '', "`r") {
    # Ignore keypresses that don't translate into printable characters
    # as well as an initial Enter keypress with nothing to submit.
    continue
  }
  # Send the character as a keypress to Read-Host to prefill its edit buffer...
  $wshell.SendKeys("{$c}")
  # ... and solicit a line of input, as usual.
  $userInput = Read-Host
  # Process the input.
  Write-Host -Fo DarkGreen "[\r] Sending: " -NoNewline
  Write-Host -Fo DarkYellow $userInput
}
```

- The above waits for a single, initial keypress.

  - If it turns out to be <kbd>ESC</kbd>, the loop is exited.
  - If it turns out to be a keypress that doesn't produce a *printable character* or produces <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it is ignored, given that there's nothing to submit.
- Otherwise:

  - The initially typed character is sent *as a keystroke* to the keyboard buffer, where `Read-Host` will pick it up; that is, the edit buffer will be prefilled with the typed character, and it will appear as if the user had just typed that character into the prompt.
  - **Caveat**: Due to use of `New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell`, this solution is **Windows-only** and **isn't fully robust**: Keeping <kbd>Shift</kbd> held down in order to type a *sequence* of uppercase letters doesn't work reliably - for *certain* characters, such as `o`, everything from the 2nd character unexpectedly remains *lowercase*<sup>[1]</sup> - see the next section for a potential workaround IF you have WSL installed.

    - On **Linux**, you could replace the keystroke-sending + `Read-Host` call more elegantly with (syntax assumes PowerShell 7.3+):

      ```bash
       $userInput = bash -c ('read -e -i ''{0}''; printf %s "$REPLY"' -f ($c -eq "'" ? "'\''" : $c)) || $(break)
      ```
    - On **macOS**, this doesn't work, unfortunately, and there's no simple workaround.

Note:

- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> exits too, but not just the loop, but invariably the *entire script* (call stack); while you cannot *prevent* that, you can perform cleanup operations and/or write to any of PowerShell's output streams *other* than the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) in the `finally` block of an enclosing [`try` / `catch` / `finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement.
- Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the loop only works *before* entering the `Read-Host` prompt; that is, once you've typed a printable character, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is your only option to *directly* abort the prompt - along with your script and all its callers.

  - As of PowerShell 7.3.4, there is *no* mechanism that would allow you to respond to keypresses in a `Read-Host` prompt in realtime, and pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> invariably just clears what has been typed so far, without leaving the prompt.

---

##### Workaround for the `.SendKeys()` problem on Windows, assuming you have WSL installed:

```bash
# Switch the console encoding (temporarily) to UTF-8, so that
# PowerShell interprets WSL output correctly.
$prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding; [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()

while ($true) {
  # Solicit an initial keypress without echoing it.
  $c = ($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')).Character
  if ($c -eq [char] 27) { # ESC pressed? Exit the loop.
    'You pressed ESC - Quitting'; break
  } 
  elseif ($c -in '', "`r") {
    # Ignore keypresses that don't translate into printable characters
    # as well as an initial Enter keypress with nothing to submit.
    continue
  }
  # Use Bash, via WSL, to prompt for the input, taking advantage of its ability
  # to pre-fill the edit buffer
  $userInput = wsl -e bash -c ('read -e -i ''{0}''; printf %s "$REPLY"' -f $(if ($c -eq "'") { "'\''" } else { $c }))
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) { 
    # Implies that Ctrl-C was pressed.
    # Exit the loop. Note that this is NOT the same as pressing Ctrl-C
    # with Read-Host, which terminates the entire script and its call stack.
    break 
  } 
  # Process the input.
  Write-Host -Fo DarkGreen "[\r] Sending: " -NoNewline
  Write-Host -Fo DarkYellow $userInput
}

# Restore the previous console endoding, if needed.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc
```

---

<sup>[1] Seemingly, the simulation of keyboard input, which involves programmatically pressing and releasing the `Shift` key, can interfere with properly detecting the physical keyboard state.</sup>

Comment: Looks nice, and thanks for info about tight loop. I assume it's the 2nd `while`, that indeed looks weird.

Comment: My bad, @not2qubit - I mistakenly thought your inner `while` loop was _polling_ for an available keystroke, but it isn't, and it is therefore _not_ a tight loop. However, the solution is still suboptimal in that if the user starts typing a string, you won't get the normal command-line editing experience (Backspace, cursor keys, ...). Please see my update, which overcomes this limitation.

Comment: As soon as I hit the `[SHIFT]` key in order to enter capital letters, I get an error: `OperationStopped: ... Line 13 ... Value does not fall within the expected range.`.

Comment: @not2qubit, sorry, a typo had crept in: ``-eq '', "`$r"`` should be ``-in '', "`$r"`` - fixed now.

Comment: It has a strange side effect of when you hold SHIFT to type more than 1 capital character, the second one is still lowercase, but not always, only just after you hit return.

Comment: @not2qubit, yes, that's unfortunate (based on my informal tests it isn't related to pressing Return, but - bizarrely - _what character_ you type). I've updated the answer to note the limitation, and I've added a WSL-based workaround that works properly - but obviously requires WSL to be installed.

Comment: oooh, ouch, that's a nasty work around! 8/  But isn't this a defect in pwsh? Anyway, we don't have WSL on any of the machines I was planning to use this on.

Comment: @not2qubit, it's a problem with _simulating_ keyboard input, which is in a layer _below_ PowerShell. As far as I can tell, the solutions presented are your best options at the moment. Related discussion: [GitHub issue #19664](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19664).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how the linked GH issue for the `-TimeoutSecond` parameter, has anything to do with this? Avoiding the WSL solution, my guess is that somehow after the first `ReadKey()` operation, the SHIFT is forgotten for the subsequent `Read-Host`, or `SendKey()`, as it only detects printable key's and not keys like [SHIFT], [CTRL] etc? So maybe possible to add detection for the SHIFT key as well, and then force `$c` toUpper()?

Comment: Even more strange. If I put a `sleep -m 500` just before the `SendKey()`, The capital letter will be detected, but only if I type it quickly, **and** with the terrible side effect of reversing the order of the characters typed! I.e. quickly typing `AB` results in displaying `BA`...

Comment: @not2qubit, you'll probably never be happy with a `SendKey()` solution - all GUI scripting is a hack that isn't fully robust. The GitHub issue I should have pointed you to is [GitHub issue #14013](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14013), which is in essence asking that the functionality of Bash's `read -e -i ...` be brought to `Read-Host` (pre-filling the edit buffer). Another hypothetical solution is if there were _peek_ functionality, e.g. `$$host.UI.RawUI.PeekKey()` / `[Console]::PeekKey()`, i.e. something that allows you to inspect a pending key _without consuming it_

Answer (score 0):

After having wasted way too much time trying to find a good solution, I got to an acceptable one, based on the hint from *mklement0*'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61121342/1147688). Next time I'm just gonna ask one of the AI's.

```
while(1) {
    while (($c=($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')).Character) -eq 0) {};
    switch -CaseSensitive ($c) {
        "`r"    { Write-Host -Fo DarkGreen "[\r] Sending: " -Non | Out-Host; Write-Host -Fo DarkYellow "$a"; $a=''}
        "`e"    { 'You pressed ESC - Quitting'; Break; }
        default { Write-Host -Fo DarkYellow "$c" -Non; $a += $c; }
    }
    if ($c -ceq "`e") { Break; } # Can also us a different character here, that can be used as a secret escape code.
}
```

Also, remember to use the case insensitive `-ceq`, and not `-eq`.
...and I'm also grateful for the simpleness of pwsh 7+ that also supports **ESC** [**`e**].

---

**UPDATE:**
Although this loop is better (easier), I still have to hit enter 2 times in my use case, as implemented in another SO question.

Other Useful References:

- https://powershell.one/tricks/input-devices/detect-key-press
- https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html